# C - Ncurses compiling error

Tags: c, ncurses

Im making a maze game where the person moves the cursor through a printf'ed maze that i created. The maze is made up of many 'F' characters that act as walls. Is there any way I can tell me program that if there is an 'F' character in the place where the cursor is about to move do the following things, such as print a message. Ive written the program below which is supposed to display a message when the cursor moves over the character "F". When i compile it, it gives me the error saying 'ncurses.c:24:14: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]'.

*THIS IS THE SECTION OF CONCERN OF THE ENTIRE PROGRAM WHICH CAN BE FOUND BELOW*

```
                if(m == 's')
            {
                if((oldy+1,x)=='F')
                {
                mvwprintw(win, 0,0,"Sorry, you cant move there.");  
                wrefresh(win);
                }
            else
                {
                move((y= oldy+1),x);
                refresh();
                oldy = y;
                }
            }
```

*THIS IS THE COMPLETE PROGRAM IF YOU WOULD LIKE TO SEE IT*

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int y = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int oldy = 0;
    int oldx = 0;
    char m = 'l';
    initscr();
    WINDOW* win;
    win = newwin(1, 40, 40 ,0);
    refresh();
    mvwprintw(win, 0,0,"First line");
    wrefresh(win);

    while(m != 'q')
    {
            m=getch();
    if(m == 's')
        {
            if((oldy+1,x)=='F')
            {
            mvwprintw(win, 0,0,"Sorry, you cant move there.");  
            wrefresh(win);
            }
        else
            {
            move((y= oldy+1),x);
            refresh();
            oldy = y;
            }
        }
    else if(m == 'd')
        {
            move(y,(x=oldx+1));
            refresh();
            oldx = x;
        }
    else if(m == 'a')
        {
            move(y,(x=oldx-1));
            refresh();
            oldx = x;
        }
    else if(m == 'w')
        {
            move((y= oldy-1),x);
            refresh();
            oldy = y;
        }
    else 
        m = 'q';
    }

    delwin(win);
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn on warnings and pay attention to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think this line is doing?

```
if((oldy+1,x)=='F')
```

The expression `(oldy+1,x)` uses the comma operator, which evaluates its first argument (`oldy+1`) for side effects and discards the result before evaluating its second argument (`x`). The result (`x`) is then compared to `'F'`.

Presumably you meant to call a function there. The curses function which returns the character at a position in a window is `mvwinch`. This will probably do what you meant:

```
if(mvwinch(win,oldy+1,x)=='F')
```